# Init pair of struct inside struct

Tags: c++, struct, enums, initialization, std-pair

I'm trying to initialize a pair inside a struct which take a struct:

```
enum HD_ERRORS{ // headers errors
    Preboot     =0,
    Loopback    =1,
    toto        =2
};

struct First_Next_ERR{
    bool First_Err;
    bool Next_Err;
    First_Next_ERR () : First_Err(0),Next_Err(0) {};    
    };


struct Func_H_Errors{
pair < HD_ERRORS, First_Next_ERR >  Preboot_er ;
Func_H_Errors() : Preboot_er (Preboot){}; 
};
```

So I'm getting this error:

> error: no matching function for call to 'std::pair::pair(HD_ERRORS)'

I just want to initialize the Enum type of my pair. I don't care for the struct because I already initialized it.

Answer (score 1):

The pair constructor takes 2 arguments.  In your case, you need an argument of type First_Next_ERR

Answer (score 0):

Try it like that:

```
struct Func_H_Errors
{
    pair <HD_ERRORS, First_Next_ERR> Preboot_er ;
    Func_H_Errors() 
        : Preboot_er ( toto, First_Next_ERR() )  
    {}
};
```